# Make primary key from index of two columns in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have working on a mongodb schema. I am looking to get primary key from { evaluatorEmail, studentID }. I want only one record for a particular pair of { evaluatorEmail, studentID }.

Below is the code of my model file.

**model.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
 
const studentRecordSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        evaluatorEmail: {type: String, required: true},
        studentName: {type: String, required: true},
        studentID: {type: Number, required: true},
    },
    {   collection: 'student-data'  }
 
)
studentRecordSchema.set('autoIndex', false)
 
studentRecordSchema.index(
    {
        evaluatorEmail : 1,
        studentID : 1
    },{
        unique : true
    }
)
 
const studentRecord = mongoose.model('studentRecord', studentRecordSchema)
 
module.exports =  {studentRecord}
```

It is generating new index on every request rather than only one record per {evaluatorEmail, studentID}.

Any help will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the problem:

*When your application starts up, Mongoose automatically calls createIndex for each defined index in your schema. Mongoose will call createIndex for each index sequentially, and emit an 'index' event on the model when all the createIndex calls succeeded or when there was an error. While nice for development, it is recommended this behavior be disabled in production since index creation can cause a significant performance impact. Disable the behavior by setting the autoIndex option of your schema to false, or globally on the connection by setting the option autoIndex to false.*

```
  mongoose.connect('mongodb://user:pass@localhost:port/database', { autoIndex: false });
  // or
  mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://user:pass@localhost:port/database', { autoIndex: false });
  // or
  animalSchema.set('autoIndex', false);
  // or
  new Schema({..}, { autoIndex: false });
```

source: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#indexes

Comment: Still facing the same issue. :(

Comment: How do you set the auto index false?

Comment: I have tried all methods expect createConnenction.


`const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const studentRecordSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        evaluatorEmail: {type: String, required: true},
        studentName: {type: String, required: true},
        studentID: {type: Number, required: true},
    },
    {   collection: 'student-data' , autoIndex: false}
)

studentRecordSchema.index(
    {
        evaluatorEmail : 1,
        studentID : 1
    },{
        unique : true
    }
)
//studentRecordSchema.set('autoIndex', false);
`

Comment: Got it done in mongodb UI by creating another column called Uid, but I am still not sure how to do the same using mongoose.

Comment: You are passing the 'autoIndex', false after you create the index. You must include the option when you create the index.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/9RSBdkAV

Comment: I tried above code. It still doesn't work. Should I use mongodb node driver instead??